# Azure - How to trigger Azure function from Queue service?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-durable-functions, azure-storage-queues, queuetrigger

New to Azure world, implementing a use case where the **runtime status** of the azure durable function is **Failed**? We need to trigger a new function which should write a status into AZURE SQL DB.

Working with Azure Durable function which contains default Instance Table Logs with respective to every instance ran by Orchestrator Function. Here we have a "runtime Status" column which value gets updated based on the function status.

Question: How & which trigger/service can to Trigger a function when the runtime status column value changes/updated to 'Failed' in the instance Table of the Azure Storage account.

During analysis - found Queues can help to trigger the function. couldn't found a example on how to connect dots here

Azure Storage Instance Table -> How to send the required dat to Queue -> How a Queue Triggers the function

I Appreciate anyone's input to serve this use case.

Answer (score 0):

The Durable Functions Extension supports [publishing events to Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-event-publishing?tabs=csharp-script) which you could directly use instead of querying the backing table.

This should be more efficient, and you could use another Azure Function that simply uses the [Event Grid binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to process those events.